# Reduce the size of a Linux VM data disk

Tags: azure, azure-disk

My Linux VMs each have two disk (OS + Data)

The data disks are currently set to 1024Gb but only contain <15Gb of content

In have two environments (test and production).  The production data disk is premium the test data disk is standard.

I want to reduce the size of the production data disk because as I discovered Premium disks are changed on the full size, not just the amount being used as standard disks are.

So before doing this in production, I wanted to try in test. I stop the VM then try to change the size of the disk through the Azure portal but I get an error stating that the new size must be greater than the current - it won't let me reduce the size.

Is that a constraint of premium disks as tell?  Is it a constraint of the Azure portal, or can I run CLI/powershell commands that can do this?  Or am I forced to create a new disk, copy data, then remove the old disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reduce the size of a disk, so you have to attach another disk and copy the content over using robocopy or other method.